# How to properly configure ssh keys to multiple remote accounts involving github and bitbucket?

Tags: git, github, ssh, bitbucket

I created and configured three ssh keys both locally and remotely as follows:

#### SSH keys - Emails

```
$> cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (E-mail Bitbucket)
ssh-rsa AAAAB3.../kJVKej/5 ricardoramos.usp@gmail.com

$> cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa_git_hub.pub (E-mail Github1 is the same account Bitbucket)
ssh-rsa AAAAB3...Iq9FkLN6L ricardoramos.usp@gmail.com

$> cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa_back_track.pub (E-mail Github2)
ssh-rsa AAAAB3N...MSdYFaZ0d ricardo.comp.ufla@gmail.com
```

**List SSH keys (Two different ssh keys with the same email)**

```
$> ssh-add -l
2048 6b:0b:dd...e6:b7 ricardoramos.usp@gmail.com (RSA)
2048 fc:20:37...1a:ec ricardo.comp.ufla@gmail.com (RSA)
2048 45:4c:92...40:70 ricardoramos.usp@gmail.com (RSA)
```

**Config ~/.ssh/config file**

```
#Default Bitbucket - User = ricardoramos
Host bitbucket.org
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

#Account GitHub1 - User = ricardousp
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_git_hub

#Account GitHub2 - User = ricardormoliveira
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_back_track
```

In addition, I also created a local repository with the name **test** and remote configuration:

```
$> git remote -v

origin  git@github.com:ricardormoliveira/testing.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:ricardormoliveira/testing.git (push)
```

But, when I try to push with my ricardormoliveira remote user the following message appears:

```
$> git push origin master
ERROR: Permission to ricardormoliveira/testing.git denied to ricardousp.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How do I do that git push with my ricardormoliveira user and not for ricardousp user? Why git is changing my users? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add the pub key to your github profile?

Comment: Both github and bitbucket offer ssh for debugging. Try that first with the `-vvv` flag.

Comment: Hello @steveax, as I do to use this -vvv flag? Could you help me please?

Comment: [github instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/), bitbucket has instructions too: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/troubleshoot-ssh-issues-271943403.html#TroubleshootSSHIssues-ssh-Tconnectiontest(GitBash/MacOSX/Linux)

Answer (score 3):

My solution was:

**My accounts:**

**Bitbucket** 
Usuário: ricardoramos
E-mail: ricardoramos.usp@gmail.com

**Github – 01** 
Usuário: ricardousp 
E-mail: ricardoramos@icmc.usp.br

**Github – 02** 
Usuário: ricardormoliveira 
E-mail: ricardo.comp.ufla@gmail.com

For each of the accounts performed the following steps:

1. `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my email"`
2. `ssh-add ~/.ssh/(key name without the .pub)`
3. After the key does not run the command `ssh-add -D`, because I
   thought that this command only wipe the chache and in fact this was
   being my mistake!
4. `ssh-add -l`
5. go to the directory `~/.ssh`
6. if there is no config file, simply create it in the directory
   `~/.ssh`
7. `sudo nano config`
8. add the following settings in the config file the ssh folder

**My final ssh configuration file:**

```
#Default Bitbucket email:ricardoramos.usp@gmail.com
Host bitbucket.org-ricardoramos
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

#Account GitHub1 email:ricardoramos@icmc.usp.br
Host github.com-ricardousp
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github

#Account GitHub2 email:ricardo.comp.ufla@gmail.com
Host github.com-ricardormoliveira
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_sec
```

After you finish creating and configuring all the keys just set the remote repositories:

1. `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
2. copy my key `ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nz... my email` to clipboard
3. in bitbucket or github access my configuration > SSH keys add the
   key

After performing all the steps the push worked normally!

Link that helped me solve the problem:

[tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574) 
[youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fnSRBRiQIU8#t=73) 
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610905/how-to-use-the-ssh-key-for-bitbucket-projects)

If I do not forget anything you think that's it! Hahaha

Answer (score 1):

Whats you did id the right way to do it all.

Its described here as well:  [Managing two ssh keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34634132/managing-two-ssh-keys/34634893#34634893)

Looks like you did not add the keys to your remote server.

---

### Multiple SSH Keys settings for different github account:

https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996

---

### ***`create different public key`***

create different ssh key according the article Mac Set-Up Git

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@youremail.com"
```

for example, 2 keys created at:

```
~/.ssh/id_rsa_activehacker
~/.ssh/id_rsa_jexchan
```

### ***`Add these two keys to the ssh-agent:`***

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_activehacker
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_jexchan
you can delete all cached keys before

$ ssh-add -D
```

### ***`check your keys`***

```
$ ssh-add -l
```

### ***`Modify the ssh config`***

```
$ cd ~/.ssh/
$ touch config
$ subl -a config
```

#### `Add the keys to the config file:`***

```
#activehacker account
Host github.com-activehacker
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_activehacker

#jexchan account
Host github.com-jexchan
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_jexchan
```

### ***`Clone you repo and modify your Git config`***

```
# clone your repo 
git clone git@github.com:activehacker/gfs.git gfs_jexchan

cd gfs_jexchan and modify git config

$ git config user.name "jexchan"
$ git config user.email "jexchan@gmail.com" 

$ git config user.name "activehacker"
$ git config user.email "jexlab@gmail.com" 

# or you can have global 
git config $ git config --global user.name "jexchan" 
git config --global user.email "jexchan@gmail.com"
```

### ***`push your code`***

```
git add .
git commit -m "your comments"
git push
```

Comment: Hello @codeWizard, I suspect that is because I have two different ssh keys with the same email, because to run the command `ssh-add -l` It appears the result: key 1 = `2048 6b:0b:dd:ca:...:b7 ricardoramos.usp@gmail.com (RSA)`
key 2 = `2048 fc:20:37:8....:6c:1a:ec ricardo.comp.ufla@gmail.com (RSA)`
key 3 = `2048 45:...2:41:d6:85:40:70 ricardoramos.usp@gmail.com (RSA)`, is it because of this that is not working?

Comment: I added the listing in question.

Comment: If you have the 2 keys under the same account in github its a problem

Comment: One key is the bitbucket and the other is with github, but the two are configured to the same email.

Comment: Email should be a problem since your host is baesd uponteh host (url) first

Comment: tru to remove one and check if its working (elimination)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105482/discussion-between-ricardoramos-and-codewizard).